# castle windsor: how to register a list programmatically (instead with a configuration file)

Tags: list, parameters, castle-windsor, castle

I would like to register an object with a list parameter, but without using a configuration file.
this is the configuration file that I currently use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<castle>
  <components>
    <component id="EmailParser"
     service="ESImportCommon.Email.IEmailParser, ESImportCommon"
     type="ESImportCommon.Email.EmailParser, ESImportCommon">
    </component>
  </components>
</castle>
```

Comment: Where's the list? Is it a list of values (e.g. int) or services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
        using ESImportCommon.Email;

        ....

        var container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter()); 
        container.AddFacility<FactorySupportFacility>();
        container.Register(Component.For<IEmailParser>().ImplementedBy<EmailParser>());
```

Note that you don't need to pass an instance of `XmlInterpreter` to the constructor if you do not want *any* configuration in your web/app.config.